# Move fields up one level in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've taken over a database and need to export data out of it, but I'm a bit stuck how to do it quickly.

This is an example of the layout of a document:

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("37035cs978952"),
   "main": {
     "432daf56676": {
       "dat": "2011-09-09T15: 52: 26+01: 00",
       "a": "a",
       "b": "c",
       }
  }
}
```

So what I would like to do is pull "dat", "a" & "b" up one level so that I can quickly do a mongo export to csv. eg mongoexport db collection -f "main.dat", "main.a". The problem is that the field below main is a randomly generated number (I don't quite know why it was put there in the first place!).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two questions: (1) does every document have a 'main' tag?;  (2) Is there ever more than one sub-document with the random hex number?  If I know that, I can construct an answer for you.

Comment: 1. Yes, every document has a main tag. 2. it's flat within the random hex. Hope these answer your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some JavaScript run from the mongo shell:

```
XDB = db.tb;  // season to taste

var cursor;
cursor = XDB.find();

do {
    var olddoc = cursor.next();
    var newdoc = {};
    var oldmain = olddoc.main;

    for( x in oldmain ) {
       var newmain = oldmain[x]; 
       newdoc.main = newmain;
    }
    newdoc._id = olddoc._id;
    XDB.update({_id: olddoc._id}, newdoc );
} while ( cursor.hasNext() );
```