# node/mongodb: howto move field up one level

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of a few million documents, with the format:

```
{
   _id: ...
   main: {
     case: ...
     csc: ...
   }
}
```

and need it to transform into:

```
{
  _id: ...
  case: ...
  csc: ...
}
```

I found an answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867521/move-fields-up-one-level-in-mongodb), but there they use the mongo shell (synchronous). I would like to do the same in node using the mongodb driver.

I've tried `cursor.each` to loop over the documents, but the insert command needs a callback, so I'm stuck with that solution:

```
coll.find().each(function(err, item) {
  newDoc.insert(item.main, function(err) {
    ???
  })
});
```

Also I've tried and `update`:

```
update({}, {$set: {case: value.case, csc: value.csc}, function(err) {
   ...
});
```

which doesn't work (as you can not use `value.case` and `value.csc` in the $set argument?)

I'm have a solution using `find` and `toArray`, looping over documents in nodejs moving the field up one level, and insert the new documents in a new collection:

```
coll.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
  for (var doc in documents) {
    newDocs.push(documents[doc].main);
  }
  newColl.insert(newDocs, function(err) {
    ...
  });
});
```

I'm interested in a maybe more efficient/elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand, try this.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
{
    $group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        case :{$first:"$main.case"},
        csc :{$first:"$main.csc"},
        }
},{
    $out:"new_collection"
}

])
```

after that you have a new collection called "new_collection" with this format

```
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "case" : 4,
    "csc" : 5
}

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "case" : 3,
    "csc" : 4
}
```

**UPDATE** 
You Can try

```
db.new_collection.update({},{$rename:{'main.case':'case','main.csc':'csc'}},{multi:true})
//now is Empty
db.new_collection.update({},{$unset:{'main':1}},{multi:true})
```

if I understand :)

Comment: No you don't understand. This is all about actually changing the current document structure using asynchronous code. It is not about presenting a view via aggregate. Nice try, but dumping a new collection has problems all of it's own.

Comment: oh ok, because I've seen that he uses `newColl.insert(newDocs, function(err) {
    ...
  });`

Comment: Thanks @Barno and @niel-lunn, I like the answer using the `update/rename`. I didn't know `rename` existed. And, I didn't want to make a new collection, it just seemed unavoidable in my own solution.